# Get lookup field with xslt

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-designer

I have the following code in XSLT (.aspx page) and I get the Id of "Evaluacion" lookup field with @EvaluacionIDLookup. I need to get the name of "Evaluacion" but the internal name is "EvalCompeEvaluacion" and if I set @EvalCompeEvaluacion intead I get a strange code.

```
</td><td class="ms-vb styleLine">
            <xsl:value-of select="@EmpleadoCargoLookup" /></td><td class="ms-vb styleLine" style="text-align:center; width: 90px;height:22px;">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@RespuestaJSON != ''">
                    <a>
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                            <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                            <xsl:text>javascript:EC.Empleados.ForEvaluation.ViewReport(</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="translate(translate(@EmpleadoCedulaLookup,'.',''),',','')"/>,
                            <xsl:value-of select="translate(translate(@EvaluacionIDLookup,'.',''),',','')"/>
                            <xsl:text>);return false;</xsl:text>                        
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <img src='/_layouts/images/DATASET_SP16.gif' alt='Ver reporte de evaluación' style="border-style: none"/>
                    </a>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </td>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post part of your XML so we can better see?

Comment: Thaks @Parfait, I already update the XML, is It ok?

Comment: Can you post the XML, not just the XSLT?